# ros_canopen PDO mapping (Schneider Motor CiA 402)

Tags: ros, can, ros-canopen

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys,

I'm at a dead-end so in need of some help from the community, please. This question follows on from a closed [GitHub issue on ros_canopen](https://github.com/ros-industrial/ros_canopen/issues/425). My problem is as follows:

- **I'm unable to do a PDO re-map procedure using ros_canopen_master.**
- If I don't do the PDO re-map procedure the Schneider Lexium 28 controller does enable voltage but halts due to an error message: "PDO packet too long".

Some background data:

1. Both EDS and DCF formats have been tried. Setting `ParameterValue` via CANeds, text file or `dcf_overlay` in driver.yaml makes no difference to the error. Looking at the source code in ros_canopen, the error seems to be that it tries to read an SDO which the package is not setup to do (bubbles up at object dictionary `1800sub1` but this doesn't seem to point to anything useful) but I am not asking it to read an SDO, just write to them in the devices pre-operational state so it can re-map the PDO.
2. ros_canopen version 0.8.5
3. TPDO & RPDO mappings as follows:

> "1A00sub0": "2"
> "1A00sub1": "0x60410010" ---------------- # statusword [2 bytes]
> "1A00sub2": "0x60610008" ---------------- # modes of operation display [1 byte]
> "1A01sub0": "1"
> "1A01sub1": "0x60640020" ---------------- # actual position value [4 bytes]
> "1600sub0: "2"
> "1600sub1": "0x60400010" ---------------- # controlword [2 bytes]
> "1600sub2": "0x60600008" ---------------- # modes of operation [1 byte]
> "1601sub0": "1"
> "1601sub1": "0x607a0020" ---------------- # target position [4 byte]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/377011/ros_canopen-pdo-mapping-(schneider-motor-cia-402)/) by [robertjbush](https://answers.ros.org/users/73762/robertjbush/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2021-04-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See this [github issue (#425)](https://github.com/ros-industrial/ros_canopen/issues/425) for corrective action. Essentially comment out line 429 `sdo.cpp` but BEWARE not recommended by maintainer of package. A more permanent fix is being investigated.

---

Originally posted by [robertjbush](https://answers.ros.org/users/73762/robertjbush/) with karma: 31 on 2021-04-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) on 2021-04-30**:
Congratulations.